# Is there some method to quickly add references, like ctrl+c and ctrl+v style?

Tags: citing, vscode

I use vscode to write some of my notes in Latex. Sometimes I need to add some references for clarity of the notes, and the normal way I do is to create a bib from Zotero, copy it at the end of my .tex file, and then cite it in the main notes.

*My question is*, is there some way that I can do this quickly using styles like easily `ctrl+c` and `ctrl+v`, such as I `ctrl+c` from Zotero and then directly `ctrl+v` in the place that I want to cite is enough?

Comment: You might want to look into [jabref]. It generates .bib files for you and provides copying citations, such as copying `\cite{citation-key}` (with a shortcut of Ctrl+K by default).

Comment: Are you asking about adding bibliography entries, or adding references to an existing bibliography?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout `reftex-cite.el`:

If you list in your `emacs` configuration a bunch of bibtex files (e.g. one listing your own publication, one listing other people's publications) listed in the variable `reftex-default-bibliography`:

```
(setq reftex-default-bibliography '(
                    "bibliographyDatabase.bib"
                    "publications-ExportedFromOrgmode.bib"
                   ))
```

Then the function `reftex-citation`  (which I have bound to `C-c b`, where `b` stands for "Bibliographical reference") will request a
regular expression to search in the database, produce a list of entries matching the regular expression, and allow to select a subset of the list (`enter` to select one, `m` to select various ones) and to insert the corresponding `\cite{}` entry.